# Build an array of classes to execute a static method with overloaded constructors in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

The following code is not correct in TypeScript. The compilier doesn't like the type of the array. "Type 'typeof FolderDetailMainComponent' is not assignable to type 'typeof BaseDetailComponent'". If the child class doesn't overload the constructor with new parameters, it does work. The type "Array" seems to be necessary to execute the static method "say".

```
export class BaseDetailComponent {
    constructor() {}

    static say(){}
}

export class FolderDetailMainComponent extends BaseDetailComponent  {
    constructor(private myIncjet: string) {  // <--- this "breaks the type"
        super();
    }

    static say() {
        console.log("Hello")
    }     
}

const example : Array<typeof BaseDetailComponent> = [ FolderDetailMainComponent];  // Error Type 'typeof FolderDetailMainComponent' is not assignable to type 'typeof BaseDetailComponent'

example.map(p => p.say())
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the problem is constructor callable/newable signature. One way (I can think of) to omit it would be using mapped types (as they map over known properties and don't carry callable signature):

```
type ExcludeCallable<T> = { [K in keyof T]: T[K] };

const example: Array<ExcludeCallable<typeof BaseDetailComponent>> = [FolderDetailMainComponent];
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwDYEMDOa4CF3ACLAwoCWSAwhALaQB2wN8A3gFByIQ1oxQCuCM0ABQBKOIzgBfZqzhcUMYglkoAniLGTmU5jBVhgcAKo0AZjxr9iHADwAVAHxwAvHFtwAZBoQokSAFxwdABuwFAA3HAoYGBIKgHBoREARsQ0ACbxwCHhmsygkLCIqBhwAGIQSGmhBESkALIkNBTUHPTwoDD0aZg4aPiEJORUtG1iMggcXLz8QmBQxEHyBpQqAJIWAFaEAVOpAOaiLGxsaDz6UCJhMtonRApKaKrqR8cTnBXAAHRIEHuCAEQACWAvgg-2E1y00l0%20jgAFEQMgeFUyD5UEkkMA7I4XOIANoAaTgqTgAGtgCoICZXABdAK2Qk0yRXZhvLhwUAoaiYgIAQSgUFU1gRSJRaJQGKxMOAVOwuBqg2aIwY9hxcDx5Uq1QG9UaStaDBpLM53K%20lCigjAzkcYE%20jzUwmEQA)

Answer (score 3):

The only way I can think of *(edit: fortunately, though, [Aleksey L. thought of an arguably better way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62754384/157247))* is to define an interface with the static method(s) you want to use from the constructors:

```
interface Sayable {
    say(): void;
}
```

and then use that interface:

```
const example : Sayable[] = [ FolderDetailMainComponent];
```

or

```
const example : Array<Sayable> = [ FolderDetailMainComponent];
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=3.9.2#code/PQKgpgHgDg9gTgFxMABAYwDYEMDOOUBCuYAImAlgJYYDCMAtrAHZhMIoDeAUCr+jExwI4AVzQJ4ACgCUnAL5cefIVgSU0KHFgCeMjgoVdQkWImTpseFADEYGACZg4ZCtQCyVJnUYDW7SAis9vhEOKTkVLQMzH683Hz8gsJiEnCSUHCUAG6qYCj02gCSTGgAVuQAXJrClEwA5rIcvMCoADwAtJ0oCAAWlPgARABGcGBYANb4vXkI2lBgA0oJvDgi82nSANxLKIYJKmoaWrqNOwloAjh2YAB0GDB1kgMAEmAY9wPSO3LLXIa1gTgADMsGg8gBlHRYIYYPLxZQ6GRVLIwSj2baGC5JFCQLCMWEoKqQ7TQ2EAbQAuigALwoMk2OyOZwRdyebwxNgU7ZcXH4270LBQdI0gB8KCgN2OMmkQA)

That works because TypeScript's type compatibility is structural (matches if it has the right things in it), not nominal (matches if it has the right name/lineage).

Comment: I would prefer this solution it it would be possible to use interfaces on static methods

Comment: @brenkdar - I'm sorry, I didn't understand the second part of that...?

Comment: It seems like TS does not support something like: class FolderDetailMainComponent implements Sayable {
   static say() {..}
}

Comment: @brenkdar - Ah, I see what you mean. You want that so you get a compiler error if you edit `FolderDetailMainComponent` and remove `say` (you'd also have to edit `BaseDetailComponent` to remove `say`, otherwise `FolderDetailMainComponent` would inherit it). If you did, though, the assignment to the array would become an error, so you'd still get proactive notification of the problem. I can see situations where I want the interface solution above, but for what you described in the question, I think I'd use Aleksey's solution.